# Export war file from windows and add it to ubuntu webapps

Tags: java, linux, windows, eclipse, tomcat

I am trying to export a war file from Eclipse (Dynamic Web Project-java) from a WindowsX64 environment and add it to an UbuntuX64 system in the tomcat6 webapp folder. When the Ubuntu-tomcat deploys the .war file i get this error on my Servlect-classes:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: beans/Show_Suggestions : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class beans.Show_Suggestions)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably compiled with a different version of Java.  Try changing your JDK settings in Eclipse and check out what version of JRE you're running on the Ubuntu machine.

On the Ubuntu machine, do the following command:
`java -version`

Make a note and compare that to what you're using in Eclipse.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to change the JDK in the Eclipse environment?

Comment: @charilaos13 right click on your project > properties > Java Compiler > Uncheck `Use compliance from execution...` and select the `compliance level` from the combobox. Set the one you have on your Ubuntu